# Angular 6 SSR : a true 404 / not found page with an 404 HTTP status code

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I struggle to settle a 404 page that returns to navigators/crawlers a specific HTTP status code : 404.
Following SSR guide in https://angular.io/guide/universal, my application is correctly served with SSR.

I set a 'PageNotfound' route  in my app-routing.module.ts :

```js
{path: '*', component: NotFoundComponent}
```

But obviously it still returns 200 as http return statuses.
How I can change http return code for this specific route ?

Answer (score 10):

For me the following snippet worked (Angular 8.2.11). No need to change the default server.ts file.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, PLATFORM_ID, Optional } from '@angular/core';
import { REQUEST } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';
import { isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';
import { Request } from 'express';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-error-not-found',
  templateUrl: './error-not-found.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./error-not-found.component.scss']
})
export class ErrorNotFoundComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any,
    @Optional() @Inject(REQUEST) private request: Request
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
      if (this.request.res) {
        this.request.res.status(404);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

And offcourse we need our routes to be something like this:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  ...
  { path: '404', component: ErrorNotFoundComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/404' }
];
```

Comment: This would import express into the frontend build.

Comment: It's just importing a typing, `Request`, from Express, not the library itself. It won't be included in the build.

Comment: works in Angular 9, thanks. Didn't work in versions before...

Comment: this works fine when I run it with dev:ssr locally, but when I upload on AWS Lambda with vendia solution, it still returns a 200

Answer (score 1):

**Outdated. Since angular 9 the issue is resolved. Use for <=8 only**

Although it is quite well-documented here https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine the proposed token does not work.

It is simply undefined in SSR (in the client it is easy to mock it).

However there is a (very) dirty solution.

Just put some marker on your 404 page (change `whatevervaluehere` to something unique and meaningless):

```
<!-- indicator for SSR to return 404 status code -->
<!-- MUST BE LEFT HERE -->
<input type="hidden" value="whatevervaluehere">
```

and in the server.ts

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', {
    req,
    res,
  }, (err: Error, html: string) => {
    res.status(html && html.includes('whatevervaluehere') ? 404 : html ? 200 : 500).send(html || err.message);
  });
});
```

Again, very, very dirty. However, works.

Comment: yeah dirty, but the only thing that worked for me as well :)

Comment: is this only work for less than Angular 9.?

Comment: Please help me out from this issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70926063/angular-9-ssr-404-not-found-page-with-status-code

Answer (score 0):

add this to the component `NotFoundComponent`

```
import {Component, Inject, OnInit, Optional, PLATFORM_ID} from '@angular/core';
import {isPlatformBrowser} from '@angular/common';
import {RESPONSE} from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';
import {Response} from 'express';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-not-found',
  templateUrl: './not-found.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./not-found.component.scss']
})
export class NotFoundComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object,
              @Optional() @Inject(RESPONSE) private response: Response) {
  }


  ngOnInit() {
    if (!isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      this.response.status(404);
    }
  }
}
```

modify server.js file to this

```
import {REQUEST, RESPONSE} from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';
import {ValueProvider} from '@angular/core';


app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) => {
  renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, {
    // Our index.html
    document: template,
    url: options.req.url,
    extraProviders: [
      // make req and response accessible when angular app runs on server
      <ValueProvider>{
        provide: REQUEST,
        useValue: options.req
      },
      <ValueProvider>{
        provide: RESPONSE,
        useValue: options.req.res,
      },
    ]
  }).then(html => {
    callback(null, html);
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Exterminator, thanks a lot for your response. Unfortunately, when I set injection of "response" field in constructor, compilation fails : `ERROR in ./node_modules/cookie-signature/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/germain.sigety/workspace-typescript/ng-pas/node_modules/cookie-signature'
ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/home/germain.sigety/workspace-typescript/ng-pas/node_modules/etag'
ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js...` Have you got an idea ?

Comment: Thanks again for your time Unfortunately, I have no server.js but a server.ts (typescript). My app.engine function call is very different : `app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));` Does your solution work with Angular 6 ? If I replace my method  by yours, it does not compile.

Comment: any progress on this issue?

Comment: @dcballs the only way I found is https://stackoverflow.com/a/57677168/1990451 ...

Comment: Please help me out for angular 9 404 status code - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70926063/angular-9-ssr-404-not-found-page-with-status-code