# Angular 6 Server Side Rendering (SSR) set status code from Component

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-universal

Is there any way to set status code like 404, 401, 500 as per requirement?

I am using Angular 6. There are lots of tutorials showing solutions but those are old and not working at all. All provides showing solutions regarding different `server.ts` file which is not related to new file showing on Angular site.
I am able to render all pages server side. When it has some unexpected content in URL, I am change route to 404 page with skipping location change option.

While calling 404 component, I want to set `statuscode = 404`.

**Server.ts**

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main');

// Express Engine
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
// Import module map for lazy loading
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
    providers: [
        provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
    ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

/* 404 status for 404Page route in both language */
app.get('/en/404Page', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).render('index', { req });
});
app.get('/de/404Page', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).render('index', { req });
});

// TODO: implement data requests securely
app.get('/api/*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).send('data requests are not supported');
});

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

**static-page-http404.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Optional, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { RESPONSE } from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-static-page-http404',
    templateUrl: './static-page-http404.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './static-page-http404.component.scss' ]
})
export class StaticPageHttp404Component implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        @Optional() @Inject(RESPONSE) private response: any,
    ) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {

        if (this.response) {
            this.response.statusCode = 404;
            this.response.statusMessage = 'Not Found';
        }

    }

}
```

Can somebody help in this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have managed to solve this by this code

```
app.engine('html', (_, options, callback) =>
  ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
    providers: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
      {
        provide: REQUEST,
        useValue: options.req,
      },
      {
        provide: RESPONSE,
        useValue: options.req.res,
      },
    ],
  })(_, options, callback)
)
```

And it's working :D

Thanks

Comment: this not working for me, can you share the code with me, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this maybe

```
import {RESPONSE} from '@nguniversal/express-engine/tokens';

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', 
  { req, 
    res, 
    bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,

    providers: [
        provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
        {
          provide: RESPONSE,
          useValue: res
        }
    ]

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For people arriving at this page for angular 8, for me this snippet worked.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58639914/9187039

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but...

Just change

```
res.render('index', { req });
```

to

```
res.render('index', { req, res });
```

It works for me. Without providers `REQUEST` and `RESPONSE`.

I tested it on Angular v.8.1