# Angular9 setting 404 HTTP status code for NotFoundPage

Tags: http-status-code-404, angular9

Angular: 9.1.2
Node: 14.15.5
OS: linux x64

I know it`s a common challenge. I got 404 page and status 200 from server instead of status 404.

I have tried various solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52663743/angular-6-ssr-a-true-404-not-found-page-with-an-404-http-status-code?noredirect=1&lq=1), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70926063/angular-9-ssr-404-not-found-page-with-status-code?noredirect=1&lq=1), and [this](https://onthecode.co.uk/blog/angular-universal-setting-http-status-code). I used services, I changed server.ts file, then I didn't changed it, whatever, nothing didn't work for me, unfortunately.

That's all I have. My NotFoundPageComponent file with routing

```
{path: '404', component: NotFoundPageComponent},
{path: '**', redirectTo: '404'}
```

and this server.ts file

```
import '@angular/localize/init';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';


// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app() {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/frontend/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

 // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run() {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

I would be grateful for any link, advice, question or example of a solution to this problem.